# Prevent the creation of a certain, standard DocType, in Documentum

Tags: java, documentum, mdd

I am using **My Documentum for Desktop**, and I had to extend the behaviour of my DocBase - as creating new DocTypes and the related TBOs -. To be precise, I have created a new DocType, called `emdd_document`; this inherits from the standard type `dm_document`. Everything works fine and `emdd_document`, with its TBO, has its own logic, derived from `dm_document`'s one.

However, *I want to prevent users from using the standard `dm_document`*, allowing them to use only the derived one (`emdd_document`), but I have no ideas about the way of doing this. If `dm_document` was a derived DocType, I could create an empty `doSave()` function in its TBO, blocking the object's saving action. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void doSave(boolean saveLock, String versionLabel, Object[] extendedArgs) throws DfException {
    DfLogger.debug(this, "This document type cannot be created!", null, null);
    //super.doSave() is not called
}
```

But, being that a standard type, I cannot follow this approach.

So, I am asking: Is there a way to prevent the doSave() excecution for a standard type? Or, strictly speaking about My Documentum for Desktop, is there some configuration that prevent users to choose that DocType, during a document's creation (as explained in the picture below)?

[image: As I try to explain in the image, I wish dm_document to be not selectable, during a saving action.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to prevent users from utilizing certain types (including built-in types) in Documentum is usually to configure the client. For most clients this is done using display configuration through the DD (Data Dictionary) mechanism.

However, for My Documentum Desktop this seems to be somewhat different. I have not used it myself, but take a look at the *My Documentum Desktop Installation and Configuration Guide 6.7.2*, page 25 -- *Object type filters preference set*:

> This sets the root object type that generates the list of object types from which users can select in the ingest dialog box. **This also hides specific object types from display in MDD.**

On page 56 -- *Define settings for an object type (Windows)*:

> `Default_Document_Object_Type=dm_document`

I guess the former configuration setting will help you in hiding dm_document, and the latter could assist you in making a default type choice for clients.

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution specifically designed for MDD works exactly as you guessed!